# Getting asymptotic lines in a electronic filter design plot

Tags: plotting, physics, logarithmic-scale

I've the following code:

```
LogLinearPlot[
 20 Log10[(5/
      Sqrt[2])*(1/(\[Sqrt]((8 f \[Pi] 56000 (5.601443110900379`*^-8) \
- 8 (1.6672176431702952`*^-7) f^3 \[Pi]^3 56000^3 \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)^2)^2 + (1 - 
            8 f^2 \[Pi]^2 56000^2 (5.601443110900379`*^-8) \
((1.6672176431702952`*^-7) + (5.601443110900379`*^-8)))^2)))], {f, 
  0.01, 1000}]
```

It is a logarithmic plot of a electronic filter.

> Now, I want to get some asymptotic lines in my plot. So at the beginning of the plot my code produces a straight line at $20\log_{10}(5/\sqrt{2})$ and further it dies asymptotic off to $-\infty$ but I want to have a dotted asymptotic line to give that in the plot.

Something like this:

[image]

The red line I got in my function and I want the blue lines that asymptoticly give my values in the plot.

Comment: Note that Version 12 introduced `Asymptotic` which when combined with `BodePlot` also addresses this issue.  See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257244/7167).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func[f_] := 
 20 Log10[(5/
      Sqrt[2])*(1/(\[Sqrt]((8 f \[Pi] 56000 (5.601443110900379`*^-8) \
- 8 (1.6672176431702952`*^-7) f^3 \[Pi]^3 56000^3 \
(5.601443110900379`*^-8)^2)^2 + (1 - 
             8 f^2 \[Pi]^2 56000^2 (5.601443110900379`*^-8) \
((1.6672176431702952`*^-7) + (5.601443110900379`*^-8)))^2)))]
```

Finding the asymptotic lines:

Horizontal asymptote:

```
a1=Limit[func[x], x -> 0]
```

> 10.9691

Oblique asymptote:

```
m = Limit[func[x]/Log[x], x -> \[Infinity]]
q = Limit[func[x] - m*Log[x], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

> -26.0577
>
> 103.815

Plot:

```
Show[LogLinearPlot[func[x], {x, 0.01, 10000}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , Frame -> True
  , GridLines -> Automatic
  , Axes -> True
  , AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}
  ]
 ,
 Plot[a1, {x, 0.01, 10000}
  , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dotted}]
 ,
 Plot[m*x + q, {x, 0.01, 10000}
  , PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dotted}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the blue lines dotted?

Comment: With the option "Dotted" in PlotStyle: see edit in my answer