# Asymptotic bode plot

Tags: plotting, functions, control-systems

Is it possible to plot an asymptotic bode plot. I am interested in verifying my straight line bode plot approximations done by hand by using mathematica but the bodeplot function generates the curved response.

Comment: Please provide the Mathematica code you used.

Comment: I am legit asking for a code or a way to get it done. I do not have a code, if I had a code I wouldn’t be asking

Comment: Please post your code about the functions or equations or data which you want to plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I draw an asymptotic bode plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/how-can-i-draw-an-asymptotic-bode-plot)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you have expressions for your straight line approximations since you have done these by hand.  To incorporate them into the `BodePlot`, include those solutions in the list of functions to be plotted:

```
BodePlot[{1/(1 + \[ImaginaryJ] w/2), 1, 1/(\[ImaginaryJ] w/2)}, {w, 
  0.0005, 100}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

If you do not have the asymptotes calculated manually, it *may be* possible to use `Asymptotic` to figure them out.  I am not convinced that this solution is robust, but it reproduces the above solution.

```
tf = 1/(1 + \[ImaginaryJ] w/2);
BodePlot[{tf, Asymptotic[tf, w -> 0], 
  Asymptotic[tf, w -> \[Infinity]]}, {w, 0.0005, 100}, 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for, then we need additional information about your question such as links to example outputs - even if they are from other software packages.